# loop to merge dataframes together with groupby sum

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a function that loops through an API to fetch the results and parse it into a dataframe:

```
consolidated_branch = DataFrame(columns=['Inventory', 'Item1', 'Item2', 'Results'])
for each_branch in branches:  
    branch_result = get_branches_details(each_branch)  # get_branch_details returns a dataframe
    print(branch_result)

# Loop results: 

      Inventory ...   Results
Year            ...                                
2015  51746398  ...   1090532
2016  33864077  ...   -6915080
2017  43410104  ...   -3224172
2018  48753351  ...   -679117

[4 rows x 9 columns]

      Inventory ...   Results
Year            ...                                               
2017  2028092   ...   6100009
2018  2150537   ...   17570443

[2 rows x 9 columns]

......
```

How do I sum each of the branches together into `consolidated_branch` dataframe?

i've tried:

```
for each_branch in get_branch_details(branches):
    consolidated_branch  = concat([consolidated_branch, branch_result], axis=0, ignore_index=True).groupby(["Item1"]).sum()

print(consolidated_branch)

# results 

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Inventory, Item1, Item2, Results]
Index: []
```

Not sure if this is the right way to be merging dataframes together?

Answer (score 0):

Create list of `DataFrame`s first in list comprehension:

```
L = [get_branches_details(each_branch) for each_branch in branches]
```

Or by loop:

```
L = []
for each_branch in branches:  
    L.append(get_branches_details(each_branch))
```

And then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
branch_result =  pd.concat(L, axis=0, ignore_index=True).groupby(["Item1"]).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example I cooked up for joining two or more dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create dummy dataframes that we need to append
adf= pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10,3), columns="a b c d".split())
bdf= pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(20,3)*100.0, columns="a b c d".split())


cond= pd.DataFrame()
for df in [adf, bdf]:
    cond=cond.append(df)
```

`cond` now has both dataframes.

Hope this is what you are looking for?